# BlackBerry MDS communication failure using Eclipse Plugin 1.3

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I'm using the BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull.1.3.0 (the full installer that comes with Eclipse bundled), and I'm getting the following message using the web browser in the simulator:

"A communication failure occured with the selected Mobile Data Service. The server may be bust, please try later. If the problem persists contact your administrator."

Here's the sequence of events:

1. Run As > BlackBerry Simulator from Eclipse.
2. MDS launches, and I can see activity.
3. Simulator launches, I click web browser icon.
4. First page loads fine, I can see activity in the MDS/cmd line window.
5. Second page hangs, no actividy in the MDS.cmd line window.

This happens without fail, every time. The solution is to kill the simulator and the MDS window, and repeat all 5 steps. As you can see, not exactly the most effective development environment.

Research found a forum post from over a year ago that mentioned this is a known issue in MDS 4.1.2, and that upgrading to 4.1.4 solves the issue. Two questions:

1. How can I update just the MDS version using the "all-in-one" Eclipse plugin?
2. If this was a known issue a year ago, it seems likely RIM would have fixed and updated the MDS version in the most recent plugin, so that makes it seem likely this isn't the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try download stand alone MDS from http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp
then use java 1.5 (be sure that paths are ok)
launch mds first then the simulator.